# UIImageView displays MUCH faster than either CG or CALayer. Anyone know why?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, core-animation, core-graphics, calayer

I've written an app to test image performance on iOS.  I've tried 3 different views, all displaying the same large PNG.  The first is a view that draws using CGContextDrawImage().  The second sets self.layer.content.  The third is a plain UIImageView.

The image used is created using -[UIImage initWithContentsOfData:] and cached in the viewController.  Each test repeatedly allocs a view, adds it to the view hierarchy and then removes it and releases it.  Timings are taken from the start of loadView to viewDidAppear and given as fps (effectively, view draws per second).

Here are the results from an iPad 1 running 5.1 using a 912 x 634 unscaled image:

```
CGContext:    11 fps
CALayer:      10 fps
UIImageView: 430 fps (!)
```

Am I hallucinating?  It seems almost impossible that UIImageView can draw that fast, but I can actually watch the images flicker.  I tried swapping between two similar views to defeat possible caching, but the frame rate was even higher.

I had always assumed that UIImageView was just a wrapper for -[CALayer setContent].  However, profiling the UIImageView shows almost no time spent in any drawing method that I can identify.

I'd love to understand what's going on.  Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that you timed in each of the cases, or a link to it.

Comment: The code is part of a larger app used to test our proprietary game code.  It'll take a couple hours to pull out the relevant bits.  In the meantime, I'd be happy to fill you in on any specific details you're missing from the above description.

Comment: "Timings are taken from the start of loadView to viewDidAppear" -- that seems a little bogus, since `viewDidAppear` might be called before the view actually shows up on screen. If you aren't forcing the screen to update, you're not really timing anything useful; you might create and destroy several UIImageViews but only one actually gets drawn. I wonder if UIImageView is setting its layer's content on-demand in `-layoutSubviews` -- that's certainly how I'd do it, to ensure that I touched the layer only once per screen update.

Comment: Very interesting, Kurt.  I knew viewDidAppear was a bit flaky, but I did not know that it can get called before a view draws.  I'll try out your suggestion and see what the results are.

Comment: OK, setting the layer's content in layoutSubviews did nothing to change the frame rate on my custom view.  Visibly, the UIImageView is redrawing at a hugely faster rate than my other views.  I'll try to get a clean copy of the app on github so people can look at it directly.

Comment: @JohnGraziano: I'm not sure what “flakiness” you're referring to, but what Kurt is referring to is [the documented behavior of the method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidAppear:): It's called when the view is added to a superview, which necessarily (in the normal case) happens before the view is told to draw.

Comment: I understand the documented behavior, but the actual behavior, as tested under gdb, is that viewDidAppear fires after the view is drawn to the screen (tested on 5.1).  You can try this yourself simply by breaking on viewDidAppear and noticing that the view has already been drawn.  The "flakiness" that I'm referring to is that viewDidAppear sometimes does not fire at all, especially for the first viewController that gets created by your app.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my idea.

When you modify a UIView hierarchy, by either adding, removing or modifying some view, no actual drawing is performed yet. Instead the view is marked with 'setNeedsDisplay', and is redrawn the next time the runloop is free to draw.

In fact, if your testing code looks something like this (I can only guess):

```
for (int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
     UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
     [mainView addSubview: imageView];
     [imageView setImage: image];
     [mainView removeSubview: imageView];
}
```

than the runloop is blocked until this for loop is done. The view hierarchy is drawn only once, the measured performance is that of allocating and initializing objects.

On the other hand, the CGContextDrawImage() is free to draw right away, I think.

Comment: Yeah, I'm definitely not doing that.  It's a reasonable supposition, though.  My test sequence returns to the run loop after every step.  We're right in the middle of a big release here at Funzio, but I'll try to get a copy of the project up on github early tomorrow.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The high FpS with UIImageView is because this does not actually redraws, but only marks the content for redrawing sometimes in the future when UIKit feels like doing it.

As a note:
What is strange though is, that the CGContextmethod is faster than the CALayermethod. I also tried these methods in a project of mine and working with CALayer is the fastest method (except using OpenGL ES of course).

Answer (score 0):

UIImageView uses a different way of rendering images that is much more efficient. You should have a look at this session video from WWDC 2011 that explains how the rendering process works: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=121